# Convert Rows to column using Pivot

Tags: sql-server-2008

My table data :

```
Empcode Empname  COmpany   Department Question                    Scale
1001    ABC       Comp1     IT        Development Opportunities    50
1001    ABC       Comp1     IT        Goals and Targets Set        30
1001    ABC       Comp1     IT        Feedback and Coaching        10
1002    XYZ       Comp1     IT        Goals and Targets Set        60
1002    XYZ       Comp1     IT        Feedback and Coaching        70
```

The query what I tried:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Question) 
                from TmpTest1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Empcode,Empname,Company,Department,' + @cols + '
        from 
        (
            select *
            from TmpTest1
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
           max(scale)
           for Question in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query)
```

It is working, but I don't want to use `execute(@query)`.
I would like a single inline-query instead.

Comment: Next time please format your example data and code snippets properly. Now i did it for you, because you are new to SO. Please read this article: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PIVOT` with exact result field list only. (There is no dynamic version of `PIVOT` as I know)

If you have dynamic field list, you have to use dynamic queries.

You can use **[sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)** if you do not want to use EXEC, but the query should be dynamic.